How to fix yellowed white DUPLO boat?
I have a large white DUPLO piece for the Sea Explorer. Part of it is yellowed. Not sure how… I thought maybe it was sun damage but not sure why that would cause it to turn yellow.
I’ve already soaked it in warm water with dish soap and bleach and it didn’t have much effect.
Any ideas to brighten this piece up?

